# How to revert back scalling of data in R?

Tags: r, scaling

I had a data set with data like this:

```
       value
[1,] 41601325
[2,] 54917632
[3,] 64616616
[4,] 90791277
[5,] 35335221
[6,]    .
  .     .
  .     .
```

which I had to scale down to range [0,1] using

```
apply(data1, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(X) (X - min(X))/diff(range(X)))
```

as I needed to fit the data in `GP_fit()` of `GPfit` package. The scaled down values became say:

```
       value
[1,] .4535
[2,] .56355
[3,] .64616
[4,] .70791
[5,] .35563
[6,]    .
  .     .
  .     .
```

After I applied `GP_fit()` on the scaled data and used `predict()` and as output I got the new values which again are in range[0,1] like:

```
         value
    [1,] .0135
    [2,] .234355
    [3,] .6716
    [4,] .325079
    [5,] .95563
    [6,]    .
      .     .
      .     .
```

but I want to take these back to the original range. How can I do that?

Basically I want to revert back/ return to original format for showing the output of `predict()`

**NOTE:** The original range is not fixed and can vary but normally the maximum value possible is about 20 million .

**UPDATE:** I tired to implement the code written by @JustinFletcher. My data was :

```
    value
 [1,]  54.2
 [2,]  53.8
 [3,]  53.9
 [4,]  53.8
 [5,]  54.9
 [6,]  55.0
 [7,]  38.5
 [8,]  38.0
 [9,]  38.1
[10,]  38.0
[11,]  38.8
[12,]  38.9
[13,]  24.3
[14,]  24.1
[15,]  24.3
[16,]  24.1
[17,]  24.4
[18,]  24.4
[19,]  57.3
[20,]  57.2
[21,]  57.6
[22,]  57.7
[23,]  58.1
[24,]  57.9
```

I wrote this to rescale it in range [0,1]:

```
data_new <- apply(data_test, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(X) (X - min(X))/diff(range(X)))
```

and I got

```
           value
 [1,] 0.885294118
 [2,] 0.873529412
 [3,] 0.876470588
 [4,] 0.873529412
 [5,] 0.905882353
 [6,] 0.908823529
 [7,] 0.423529412
 [8,] 0.408823529
 [9,] 0.411764706
[10,] 0.408823529
[11,] 0.432352941
[12,] 0.435294118
[13,] 0.005882353
[14,] 0.000000000
[15,] 0.005882353
[16,] 0.000000000
[17,] 0.008823529
[18,] 0.008823529
[19,] 0.976470588
[20,] 0.973529412
[21,] 0.985294118
[22,] 0.988235294
[23,] 1.000000000
[24,] 0.994117647
```

then to revert it back to original scale I wrote this:

```
data_revert <- apply(data_new, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(X, Y) (X + min(Y))*diff(range(Y)), Y=data_test)
```

and I got

```
 value
 [1,] 849.5
 [2,] 849.1
 [3,] 849.2
 [4,] 849.1
 [5,] 850.2
 [6,] 850.3
 [7,] 833.8
 [8,] 833.3
 [9,] 833.4
[10,] 833.3
[11,] 834.1
[12,] 834.2
[13,] 819.6
[14,] 819.4
[15,] 819.6
[16,] 819.4
[17,] 819.7
[18,] 819.7
[19,] 852.6
[20,] 852.5
[21,] 852.9
[22,] 853.0
[23,] 853.4
[24,] 853.2
```

This output is not correct.

Comment: order of operations - to scale back you are doing (A + B) * (C - D) but it should be A * (C - D) + B

Comment: to revert you did data_revert <- apply(data_new, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(X, Y) (X + min(Y))*diff(range(Y)), Y=data_test)

Comment: it should be data_revert <- apply(data_new, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(X, Y) X*diff(range(Y)) + min(Y), Y=data_test)

Comment: just based on Roman's answer below - i didn't look over the process E2E

Comment: not a problem, don't forget to accept an answer at some point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simple algebra. To scale data, you calculate

```
n = (e - e_min)/(e_max - e_min)
```

Now you need back e, based on arbitrary `e_min` and `e_max`. It is trivial to show that

```
n(e_max - e_min) + e_min = e
```

Example:

```
e <- 1:10
n <- (e - min(e))/(max(e) - min(e))
new.e <- (n*(10-1)) + 1

> all(e == new.e)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Sorry for a bit late response.I think I wasn't clear enough in my explanation above. I don't want to get beck `e` but revert a different number to the range of `e`. So for your example after you got `n` from scaling `e`, you calculated another number `n2` from some computation over `n` and now I want to take this `n2` into the range in which `e` was.

Comment: I have done some modification in my post above but the output that I am getting is not correct. Can you have a look at the update section in my post above?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to apply the inverse of the function FUN to the output data. This requires the original data be passed to the function.

```
apply(dataOutput, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(X, Y) (X + min(Y))*diff(range(Y)), Y=data1)
```

For a great description of the 'apply' function, see [here](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/).

P.S.: Romans response is exactly the same idea, I just implemented it with your variables, using `apply`, because I thought it was interesting.

Comment: I tried to implement your function but the output is not coming correct. I have modified my code above for you to have a look.

Comment: There is an error in `Function(X,Y)` you have mentioned. The order is not correct.